# MongoDB aggregation with $lookup only include (or project) some fields to return from query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

In mongo, after doing an `aggregation` with `$lookup`, I would like the request to return only some fields and not the whole document.

I have the following query :

```
db.somecollection.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "campaigns",
        localField: "campId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "campaign"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$campaign"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "entities",
        localField: "campaign.clientid",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "campaign.client"
    }
}]);
```

This request will return me this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56cc7cd1cc2cf62803ebfdc7"),
"campId" : ObjectId("56c740e4479f46e402efda84"),
"articleId" : ObjectId("56c742c06094640103ba3843"),
"campaign" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c740e4479f46e402efda84"),
    "clientid" : ObjectId("56c740b8479f46e402efda83"),
    "client" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c740b8479f46e402efda83"),
            "username" : "someusername",
            "shhh" : "somehashedpassword",
            "email" : "mail@mail.com",
        }
    ]
}
```

The request works well, but I would like to filter the fields in `campaign.client` to only get for example `_id` and `username`. Is there a way to do this in a MongoDB `aggregate` request?

Comment: use a `$project` stage.

`{ 
     $project : {
                         _id1 : 1,
                         campId : 1,
                         articleId : 1,
                         campaign._id  :  1,
                         campaign.clientid : 1,
                         campaign.client._id : 1,
                         campaign.client.username : 1
                     }
}`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera you should transform it in an answer, you just saved my day!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Just to help others with this, @SiddhartAjmera has the right answer, I only needed to add double quotes for nested values like "campaign.clientid".

The final code should be:

```
db.somecollection.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "campaigns",
          "localField": "campId",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "campaign"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$campaign"
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "entities",
          "localField": "campaign.clientid",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "campaign.client"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 1,
          "campId": 1,
          "articleId": 1,
          "campaign._id": 1,
          "campaign.clientid": 1,
          "campaign.client._id": 1,
          "campaign.client.username": 1
        }
      }
]);
```

Comment: why do we add $unwind? why it is needed?

Comment: @Faisal it will return campaign as an array, if you don't do $unwind

Comment: Hey... is there a way to just return everything (in project) from the parent and only specific fields from the child.  ( I used " * " as indicator )  eg:  $project: {
          " * ": 1,
          "campaign._id": 1,
          "campaign.clientid": 1,
          "campaign.client._id": 1,
          "campaign.client.username": 1
        }

Comment: @MLissCetrus did you find way to do so?

Comment: @MLissCetrus  AlpeshVasani  did you find way to do ?

Comment: using $project at the end can be hectic, one has to mention a lot of fields to select/unselect. Rather use pipeline within $lookup and write a $project wihtin the pipeline instead.

Answer (score 28):

Using `pipeline` and `$project` inside `$lookup`

```
db.somecollection.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "campaigns",
        localField: "campId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "campaign"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$campaign"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "entities",
        let: { client_id: "$campaign.clientid" },    
        pipeline : [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$client_id" ] } }, },
            { $project : { _id:1, username:1 } }
        ],
        as: "campaign.client"
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little thing to the previous answer: You can put a 0 to a project item that you want to ignore and the rest will be retrieved, so you don´t need to write all the list with 1:

```
db.somecollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "campaigns",
      "localField": "campId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "campaign"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$campaign"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "entities",
      "localField": "campaign.clientid",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "campaign.client"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "campaign.client.shhh": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is very late to answer to this question. But in my opinion, an update can sometimes prove to be very beneficial.
The project stage is great but you'd still be requesting for the entire dock in the `$lookup` stage. The fields are only filtered in the projection stage following it.
After the release of MongoDB 3.6, you can now add a pipeline to a `$lookup` stage, to specify multiple join conditions. Find more details in their official docs.
[Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup)
You can transform your aggregation pipeline as follows, to get the desired result:

```
db.somecollection.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "campaigns",
        localField: "campId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "campaign"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$campaign"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "entities",
        let: {clientid: '$campaign.clientid'},
        pipeline: [
           { '$match': 
             { '$expr': 
               { 
                  '$eq': ['$_id', '$$clientid']   
               }
             }
           },
           { '$project': 
              '_id': 1,
              'username': 1
           }
        ]
        as: "campaign.client"
    }
}]);
```

This way you can filter the fields of the joined collection right inside the `$lookup` stage.
Notice the `$$` sign inside the `$match` stage of inner pipeline. It is used to denote a custom field defined inside the `let` block.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, I found this way to solve this problem, it seems more compact and readable:

```
const query = [
  { $match: match },
  {
    $lookup: {
      'from': 'accounts',
      'localField': 'course_account_owner_id',
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'accountTmp'
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: '$accountTmp', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      'account.account_name': '$accountTmp.account_name',
      'account.account_logo': '$accountTmp.account_logo',
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
        'accountTmp': 0
    }
  }
];
```

It works because of specific behavior of $project stage which, *when excluding unnecessary fields, still leaves all the main fields in the output*, but as soon as you specify at least one subdocument field that you want to include, it immediately turns off all the main fields.